# Updating ProgressBar while Async and Await fetching HttpRequest in C# Caliburn Micro WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, caliburn.micro

I hope to update the progress bar status while downloads string from HttpGet Request.
While fetching data in OnActivate Methods of Screen Class, progress is not updating.

Here is my code of the screen.

```
public class LoadingAccountInfoViewModel:Screen, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        // Loading Progrss Bar...
        private int loadingAccountInfoProgressBar;
        public int LoadingAccountInfoProgressBar
        {
            

            get { return loadingAccountInfoProgressBar; }
            set
            {
                if (loadingAccountInfoProgressBar == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                loadingAccountInfoProgressBar = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LoadingAccountInfoProgressBar);
            }
        }

        public LoadingAccountInfoViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        protected async override void OnInitialize()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                loadingAccountInfoProgressBar = 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    loadingAccountInfoProgressBar += 10;
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }



        protected override async void OnActivate()
        {
            base.OnActivate();
            User currentUser = Global.currentUser;
            XCService xcService = new XCService();
 
            LiveStream[] liveStreams = await xcService.GetLiveStreams(currentUser.username, currentUser.password, "get_live_streams");
            VodStream[] vodStreams = await xcService.GetVodStreams(currentUser.username, currentUser.password, "get_vod_streams");
            SerieStream[] serieStreams = await xcService.GetSerieStreams(currentUser.username, currentUser.password, "get_series");

            // loadingAccountInfoProgressBar += 10;

            _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new LoadingInfoDoneMessage());

        }

        protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
        {
            base.OnDeactivate(close);
        }
    }
```

The xaml of UserControl about this class is like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProIPTV.Pages.Content.Views.LoadingAccountInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProIPTV.Pages.Content.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel >
            <Image Source="logo.png" Height="59" />
            <TextBlock Text="s t r i m o" FontSize="68" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#808182" Margin="0,0,0,188" />
            <TextBlock Text="LOADING ACCOUNT" FontSize="30" Foreground="#808182" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,62.5"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="LoadingAccountInfoProgressBar" Value="{Binding Path=LoadingAccountInfoProgressBar}" Style="{DynamicResource CornerProgressBar}" Height="12" Width="592" Foreground="#80F5F5F5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I did fetching Data with HttpGetRequest in OnActivate Method.

And ProgressBar status Updating is in OnInitialize() Method.

Please help me to fix update progress bar report while fetching data.

I am a new in Caliburn Micro WPF MVVM. So please guide me how to fix.

Comment: Normally you should get the progress from some where else. In that case it wont update the GUI. To update the GUI,    change the code like this:     Task.Delay(120); loadingAccountInfoProgressBar += 10;

Comment: This would a temp. solution. You may change your approach

Comment: I'm not sure how you're updating "progress". You're just increasing the progress value from 2 to 52 in a weird short loop. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` in combination with `async-await`?

Comment: @JinYongYoo1994: Why don't you set the progress in the `OnActivate()` method where you perform the actual work? What's the purpose of the `for` loop in `OnInitialize()`...?

Comment: I don't know how to update the progress report. That is my trying temp code.
I only tried but not working all.So I hope you guys give me a sample code how to update the report while fetching httpgetrequest async-await.
Where is the code what I can refer? Hope you will help me. Thank you in anvance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used IProgress and send IProgress Status as a Paramter when I call the asynchronize Function.

You can get the best solution in @TimCorey's Video.

Here is the link.
[Asyncronize Downloading with ProgressBar Updating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTKGRJy5P2M&t=1344s)

I hope this would help you.